# using linq to discover a duplicate variable inside an object in a list, then use another variable in said object which contains the duplicate objectId

Tags: c#, .net, linq, duplicates

i'm new to linq and i've tried this function which should check for duplicates. what i want to do is to check through my list of buildingobjects to check if any buildingobject contains an objectID identical to another buildingObject in the list. finally i want to use the GUID of the buildingObject which had a duplicate, and print it to my log for the user to see.

```
public class FMBuildingObject
{
    public Int64 ObjectId { get; set; }

    public string GUID { get; set; }
}
```

the building object is bigger, but this is the values i'm using.
next i'm trying to use the buildingobjects, find duplicates and then print the GUID out. however i can't figure out how to access that GUID.

```
var query =
buildingObjects
    .GroupBy(x => new { x })
    .Select(group => new { Name = group.Key, Count = group.Count() })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count);


foreach (var q in query)
{
    var updateLog = new LogServiceModel()
    {
        LogType = LogTypes.Warning, Parameters = { {?GUID?}}, LogTitle = "You have used two different classifications on a same Buildingobject in {0}. "
    };

    logService.Create(updateLog);
}
```

Comment: What's this supposed to show? _" Buildingobject in {0}"_?

Comment: I want to point out some things in your code, Why is your GUID `string`? There is built in `Guid` type. `GroupBy(x => new { x }) will not work in your situation, also you can write only `GroupBy(x => x )`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return a `List<string>` containing the GUID's of the objects which has duplicate `ObjectId`'s:

```
var result = buildingObjects
    .GroupBy(b => b.ObjectId)
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .SelectMany(g => g.Select(b => b.GUID)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get duplicate objects by:

```
var query = buildingObjects.GroupBy(x => new { x.ObjectId, x.GUID })
                           .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                           .Select(group => new { Name = group.Key, group.Key.GUID, group.Key.ObjectId }); //I don't know what is Name and why it's equal to Key
```

Then inside your foreach loop:

```
foreach (var q in query)
{
    var updateLog = new LogServiceModel()
    {
        LogType = LogTypes.Warning, Parameters = q.GUID, LogTitle = $"You have used two different classifications on a same Buildingobject, Id: {q.ObjectId}. "
    };

    logService.Create(updateLog);
}
```

Or you can simply do:

```
var query = buildingObjects.GroupBy(x => new { x.ObjectId, x.GUID })
                           .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                           .Select(group => new LogServiceModel() 
                            { 
                                LogType = LogTypes.Warning, 
                                Parameters = group.Key.GUID, 
                                LogTitle = $"You have used two different classifications on a same Buildingobject, Id: {group.Key.ObjectId}." 
                            });
```